# File arrangement in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I'm seeking SQLite file in simulators file system. but why when SQLite file is nestled (actually) in:

> /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/58B5B431-D2BB-46F1-AFF3-DFC789D189E8/data/Containers/Data/Application/6F3B985F-351E-468F-9CFD-BCBE217A25FB/Documents

But in code I need to search it .applicationSupportDirectory and then immediately in applicationSupportDirectory I found it.

```
  private var applicationSupportURL: URL {
  let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .applicationSupportDirectory,
.userDomainMask, true)
    .first
   return URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
  }
   private lazy var storeURL: URL = {
 let storeFileName = "\(self.storeName).sqlite"
 return URL(fileURLWithPath: storeFileName,
 }()
relativeTo: self.applicationSupportURL)
 private var storeModel: NSManagedObjectModel? {
 return
NSManagedObjectModel.modelVersionsFor(modelNamed: modelName)
.filter {
    self.store(at: storeURL, isCompatibleWithModel: $0)
}.first
}
```

Actually there is no applicationSupportDirectory. why?

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the document directory with this line of code:
All components before are used by iOS to locate you app container.

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!
```

Comment: this is not the answer for the question